# Hierarchy of Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Please guide me about the hierarchy of Yii Framework i.e in which directory do we put html, css, javascript files and associate them with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the documentation (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/)

To answer your question:

> **backend:** the backend application which is mainly used site
> administrators to manage the whole system.
>
> **frontend:** the frontend
> application which provides the main interfaces to our target end
> users.
>
> **console:** the console application that consists of the console
> commands needed by the system.
>
> **common:** the directory whose content are
> shared among the above applications. As we can see, we divide the
> whole system into three applications: backend, frontend and console.
> If needed, we can add more applications (e.g. api, to provide Web API
> service). We use common to store files that are shared among the
> applications.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged the question with Yii2 as well, here is the typical directory strucuture of Yii2 Advanced Template:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-directories.md

> **Directories**
>
> The root directory contains the following subdirectories:
>
> `backend` - backend web application.
>
> `common` - files common to all applications.
>
> `console` - console application.
>
> `environments` - environment configs.
>
> `frontend` - frontend web application.
>
> Root directory contains a set of files.
>
> `.gitignore` contains a list of directories ignored by git version
>   system. If you need something never get to your source code
>   repository, add it there.
>
> `composer.json` - Composer config described in Configuring Composer.
>
> `init` - initialization script described in Configuration and
>   environments.
>
> `init.bat` - same for Windows.
>
> `LICENSE.md` - license info. Put your project license there.
>   Especially when opensourcing.
>
> `README.md` - basic info about installing template. Consider replacing
>   it with information about your project and its installation.
>
> `requirements.php` - Yii requirements checker.
>
> `yii` - console application bootstrap.
>
> `yii.bat` - same for Windows.
>
> There are three applications in advanced template: frontend, backend
>   and console. Frontend is typically what is presented to end user, the
>   project itself. Backend is admin panel, analytics and such
>   functionality. Console is typically used for cron jobs and low-level
>   server management. Also it's used during application deployment and
>   handles migrations and assets.
>
> There's also a `common` directory that contains files used by more than
>   one application. For example, `User` model.
>
> Frontend and backend are both web applications and both contain the
>   `web` directory. That's the webroot you should point your web server to.
>
> Each application has its own namespace and alias corresponding to its
>   name. Same applies to the common directory.

The css, js for frontend or backend application is generally stored inside the corresponsing `web/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I use follow strukture:

### config

### environments

### runtime

### vendor

- my-modules

  - frontend
  - backend
- other vendor

  - bum
  - uuu

### www-frontend

- assets
- index.php

### www-backend

- assets
- index.php

### www-other-end

- assets
- index.php

All install/update by composer.In config directory set specific configuration.  Can setup unlimeted www.